# Runtime annotations annotated on a filed in kotlin class are not generated correctly

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin compiler remove the Java runtime annotation annotated on a field.The annotation is shown below.

```
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonAnnotation
public @interface JsonDeserialize
```

I declared it on a field, as seen below.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = IDEncryptJsonSerializer::class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = IDDecryptJsonDeserializer::class)
@Column(name = "sku_id", nullable = false)
open var skuId: Long = 0L
```

The annotation doesn't work. Then, I take a fist look at the class file, as seen below.

```
@field:javax.persistence.Column public open var skuId: kotlin.Long
```

The JsonDeserialize and JsonSerialize annotation are dismiss.
The two annotations are work well in Java.
My kotlin version is 1.1.4.
How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Hi, I tried that exact example with Kotlin `1.1.3-2` and `1.1.4-2`. Works for both of them. Which decompiler do you use? Could you maybe provide a tiny-tiny github repo where you reproduce the problem?

Comment: @guenhter Thank you for you reply, I explained the reason on the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason that result in the phenomenon.
If I declare a variable in class constructor, some of annotations annotate on that variable may cannot be compiled correctly.
Some of annotations may be lost because of kotlin compiler bug.
Then, I move the variable in the class body. Everything work well.

Comment: @KirillRakhman  I tried to login the website. Unfortunately, It always redirects to the login page, when I click the login button. I have @  kotlin office twitter. I'm waiting for reply.